# removing patterns in values in an R dataframe

Tags: r, data-cleaning

In my dataframe below, I would like to remove the following:

1. " and "
2. " and the "
3. ", Fed. Sts."
4. ", Republic of"
5. " of Great Britain and Northern Ireland"

```
    d <- data.frame(LOCATION = c("Antigua and Barbuda", 
                                 "Bosnia and Herzegovina",
                                 "Central Europe and the Baltics",
                                 "Micronesia, Fed. Sts.",
                                 "South Sudan, Republic of",
                                 "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland"))
```

I would directly change e.g. 'Antigua and Barbuda' to 'AntiguaBarbuda' using

```
d$LOCATION[d$LOCATION == "Antigua and Barbuda"] <- "AntiguaBarbuda"
```

but I have a large dataset with many different values that exhibit these patterns, and I would like to be able to remove these patterns from all the values in the variable in one step if possible, rather than on a specific case by case basis.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Note: you'll find that order of the patterns is important. For instance, removing `" and "` first will negate pattern 5. Target the longest chains first.

Comment: kerryp, please either accept one of the answers or comment why they don't resolve your question.

Answer (score 4):

Using `d` from the question use `gsub` as shown:

```
pats <- c(" and ", " and the ", ", Fed. Sts.", ", Republic of", 
  " of Great Britain and Northern Ireland")
pat <- paste(pats, collapse = "|")  # combine into single pattern
transform(d, LOCATION = gsub(pat, "", LOCATION))
```

giving:

```
               LOCATION
1        AntiguaBarbuda
2     BosniaHerzegovina
3 Central EuropeBaltics
4            Micronesia
5           South Sudan
6        United Kingdom
```

### Order

Note that we did *not* reorder the strings to be matched.  In fact, **there is no point in reordering the strings to be matched as long as the default R regular expression engine is used.** We explain this in the rest of the section.

You might think (or at least that is what I thought) that the regular expression works eagerly so it will take the leftmost match in a series of alternatives even if a longer one follows with the shorter one as prefix but it turns out that that is not the case in R. This is sometimes referred to as [regex-directed vs text-directed regular expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) and it seems that the default regular expression engine in R is text-directed. For example, below `ab` gets removed even though a strict left to right eager matching process would have removed `a` so that `ab` is not matched.

```
gsub("a|ab", "", "xabcy") # text oriented
## [1] "xcy"
```

However, if we use the perl engine then it is regex-directed and does eager left to right matching.

```
gsub("a|ab", "", "xabcy", perl = TRUE) # regex oriented
## [1] "xbcy"
```

Comment: thanks for the clear and useful explanation of the text oriented/regex oriented gsub. I like how your method outputs an edited dataframe. Ideally I would like to be able to scale up with a lot more patterns - how would you go about that, while ensuring they're ordered by size? When you say that there's no point reordering as long as the default engine is used, do you mean just in this specific example or more generally? Thanks again

Comment: *Ideally I would like to be able to scale up with a lot more patterns - how would you go about that, while ensuring they're ordered by size"  No.  There is no point in ordering them by size. It makes no difference at all what the order is. That is the whole point of the last section of the answer.  This holds for the example in the question and in general.  The comment under the question claiming that "you will find that order is important" is false if you use a single `gsub` pattern of alternatives with the default regular expression engine as we do here.

Answer (score 3):

Order will matter here. I'll create a `translations` frame that provides patterns and the substitutions for them, and use `gsub` iteratively on them. The use of `Reduce` is because we need a cumulative effect (whereas `lapply` or its kin will not).

```r
translations <- data.frame(
  ptn = c("and ", " and the ", ", Fed. Sts.", ", Republic of", " of Great Britain and Northern Ireland", "Antigua and Barbuda"),
  subst = c("", "", "", "", "", "AntiguaBarbuda")
)
translations <- translations[order(-nchar(translations$ptn)),]
translations
#                                      ptn          subst
# 5  of Great Britain and Northern Ireland               
# 6                    Antigua and Barbuda AntiguaBarbuda
# 4                          , Republic of               
# 3                            , Fed. Sts.               
# 2                               and the                
# 1                                   and
```

With this,

```r
Reduce(function(txt, i) gsub(translations$ptn[i], translations$subst[i], txt),
       seq_len(nrow(translations)), init = d$LOCATION)
# [1] "AntiguaBarbuda"        "Bosnia Herzegovina"    "Central EuropeBaltics"
# [4] "Micronesia"            "South Sudan"           "United Kingdom"
```

Comment: thanks for this - I really like the idea of creating a translations dataframe (in reality I have a lot more changes to make than in this reprex so that seems like an efficient way of doing it). One more question though - how would I go about changing the observations in the dataframe? I see that your Reduce command outputs a character vector. How would I take that forward to change the observations in d?

Comment: Your column here has six rows, and this call returns six strings. You can just assign it, as in `d$LOCATION <- Reduce(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT. As @r2evans rightly points out, order matters here, so their approach is more generalisable beyond this example.

It's perhaps easiest to first make a vector of patterns, and then use `dplyr::mutate` and `stringr::str_remove_all` to remove patterns from the column.

```
d <- data.frame(LOCATION = c("Antigua and Barbuda", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Central Europe and the Baltics", "Micronesia, Fed. Sts.", "South Sudan, Republic of", "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland"))
words = c(" and ", " and the ", ", Fed. Sts.", ", Republic of", " of Great Britain and Northern Ireland")
d %>% dplyr::mutate(LOCATION = 
    stringr::str_remove_all(LOCATION, paste(words, collapse="|")
        )
    )
```

```
                   LOCATION
1            AntiguaBarbuda
2         BosniaHerzegovina
3 Central Europethe Baltics
4                Micronesia
5               South Sudan
6            United Kingdom
```